# How to remove_query_arg() for paginate_links()

Tags: wp-query, paginate-links

I implemented a pagination using `paginate_links()` like below:

```
<?php
function wpse229670_pagination( $query = false ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $query = $query ? $query : $wp_query;

    $total_pages = $query->max_num_pages;
    $big = 999999999;
    if ( $total_pages > 1 ) {
        echo '<nav class="navigation posts-navigation" role="navigation">';
            echo '<strong>'. __( 'Pages:', 'text-domain' ) .'</strong> ';
            echo paginate_links( array(
                        'base' => ,
                        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                        'total' => $total_pages
                    ) );
        echo '</nav>';

    } //endif ( $total_pages > 1 )

}
```

And I can easily display my pagination using `wpse229670_pagination();` within loop, or for any custom loop, I can pass the local query as a parameter.

It's working fine.

Scenario is, I'm adding some query args like this to display a modal warning to the user:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'my_tax' );
$term_link = get_term_link( $term_id, 'my_tax' );
$parameterized_url = add_query_arg( 'from_expired', 1, $term_link );

wp_redirect($parameterized_url);
exit;
```

But the pagination links continue to display the warning, as because I cannot `remove_query_arg()` from the query and the following pages contains the argument as well.

I think it would be better if I can remove necessary [one time] query_args inside my pagination function. You know I cannot do:

```
//$query = remove_query_arg( 'from_expired', $query );
```

because `$query` inside my function is an object.

So, how can I `remove_query_arg()` from a `$wp_query` object or from `paginate_links()`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure if you mean this kind of approach:

```
add_filter( 'paginate_links', function( $link )
{
    return  
       filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'from_expired' )
       ? remove_query_arg( 'from_expired', $link )
       : $link;
} );
```

to remove the `from_expired` from the pagination links if it's in the current GET query.

Comment: Not necessary how I meant it. A working solution was necessary. +1 for the solution. Working on the first hit. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: There might be a way to only apply this to your custom pagination function, I first forgot a ; but I added that to the code, so you probably tried  the fixed version. Glad to hear it somewhat worked for you ;-) @MayeenulIslam

Comment: I copied the concept, not the code itself - that might be the issue. ;-)

Comment: That sounds like a good general advise on how to use this site, conceptually  ;-) @MayeenulIslam